# Search and put a sub HTML text inside a newly created span, preserving the HTML structure as much as possible

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, algorithm

Consider the following *example* HTML which I need to highlight a search text `192.168.1.1`. This is just an example, the text search and HTML structure are totally arbitrary because it will be run on end-user websites with their inputs. The program will also perform additional operations on the inserted `span`, not just highlighting (for example displaying a tooltip when hovering but this is not an issue as long as I have a `span` inserted).

EDIT: I just found out a new line would result in space in between which `textContent` won't be correct anymore. However I will keep them there for better visual. You can check the snippet below for correct HTML code

```html
<div>
    <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
    <em>is</em>
    <span class="ip-1">192</span>.
    <span class="ip-2">168</span>.
    <span class="ip-3">1</span>.
    <span class="ip-4">1</span>
</div>
```

Using `textContent` or `innerText`, it's easy to find the closest element with the subtext I need (the `div` in the example has the full `192.168.1.1` text). However the next step I want to do wrap those parts without breaking the original structure or other HTML/CSS `class` or properties. Ideally, I'd like to have the final HTML to be:

```html
<div>
    <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
    <em>is</em>
    <span class="my-highlight-span"><span class="ip-1">192</span>.
    <span class="ip-2">168</span>.
    <span class="ip-3">1</span>.
    <span class="ip-4">1</span></span>
</div>
```

Using deep-first search I can easily get to the `div`, but then I have no idea how to proceed from there. There's also this tricky case:

```html
<div>
    <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
    <em>is
    <span class="ip-1">192</span>.</em>
    <span class="ip-2">168</span>.
    <span class="ip-3">1</span>.
    <span class="ip-4">1</span>
</div>
```

I think if there is a solution, this should be the easiest way to achieve it:

```html
<div>
    <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
    <em>is
    <span class="my-highlight-span"><span class="ip-1">192</span>.</span></em><span class="my-highlight-span">
    <span class="ip-2">168</span>.
    <span class="ip-3">1</span>.
    <span class="ip-4">1</span></span>
</div>
```

The code will be executed in Chrome extension environment if it's relevance but I believe this should be a pure browser Javascript problem.

---

Here's a snippet so you can try out:

```js
function transform(el, text) {
  // Transform this Element to highlight text
}

const text = "192.168.1.1";
transform(document.querySelector("#case-1"), text);
transform(document.querySelector("#case-2"), text);
transform(document.querySelector("#case-simple"), text);
```

```css
.my-highlight-span {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Case 1:</p>
<div id="case-1">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is</em>
  <span class="ip-1">192</span>.<span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span>
</div>

<p>Case 2:</p>
<div id="case-2">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is
        <span class="ip-1">192</span>.</em><span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span>
</div>

<p>Simple case:</p>

<div id="case-simple">
  The computer address is 192.168.1.1
</div>

<hr />

<p>Desired Result:</p>

<div id="case-1-result">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is</em>
  <span class="my-highlight-span"><span class="ip-1">192</span>.<span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span></span>
</div>
<div id="case-2-result">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is
        <span class="my-highlight-span"><span class="ip-1">192</span>.</span></em><span class="my-highlight-span">
        <span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span></span>
</div>

<div id="case-simple-result">
  The computer address is <span class="my-highlight-span">192.168.1.1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your question needs to be more clearly defined. e.g. (1) Are you always searching for the address `192.168.1.1` or will it be dynamic? (2) Will it always be IPv4 or potentially IPv6? (3) Will the address units always be in `span`s with `class="ip-1"` etc. ?

Comment: @jsejcksn thanks for the comment. I will clarify. All of them are dynamic (i.e. the search text, the HTML structure, etc.). Nothing is fixed since it will be run inside end user's arbitrary website

Comment: My first thought about how to solve this would be something like: get all text nodes in the document and iterate combining them into groups finding the combinations which match the search string... then for each node of each matching group, replace the node with the node wrapped in your styled span.

Comment: @jsejcksn thanks I will try this. I am attempting to solve it by myself as well, by going through siblings and replacing them one by one but yours seem to be better especially since a sibling may even contain multiple matches.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info about the Range API: very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finally get the answer using [`Range` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), credit to awesome explanation [here](https://javascript.info/selection-range) and a subtle workaround of [`Range.surroundContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents).

- Using `scanForText` method I recursively scan for `textContent` of `TEXT_NODE`s to determine the start and end of a search term.
- I then use `Range` API to select and extract the content and insert it back after surrounding it with my `span`.

There is some limitation obviously but this should work for most cases. For example, in case 2, my code would generate an extra empty `<span class="ip-1">` inside `<em>`.

```js
function scanForText(el, expectingStart, expectingEnd, result) {
  if (el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    const nodeContent = el.textContent;

    result[4] += nodeContent;
    const currText = result[4];

    if (expectingStart < currText.length && !result[0]) {
      result[0] = el;
      result[1] = expectingStart - (currText.length - nodeContent.length);
    }

    if (expectingEnd <= currText.length && !result[2]) {
      result[2] = el;
      result[3] = expectingEnd - (currText.length - nodeContent.length);

      return;
    }
  } else {
    for (let childEl of el.childNodes) {
      scanForText(childEl, expectingStart, expectingEnd, result);

      if (result[2]) { // When already found ending, return
        return;
      }
    }

  }
}

function transform(el, text) {
  const fullText = el.textContent;
  const startIndex = fullText.indexOf(text);
  const endIndex = startIndex + text.length;

  const scanState = [null, -1, null, -1, ""];
  scanForText(el, startIndex, endIndex, scanState);

  const [startNode, startRangeIndex, endNode, endRangeIndex] = scanState;
  if (!startNode || !endNode) {
    console.warn("This should not be happening");
    return;
  }

  const range = new Range();
  range.setStart(startNode, startRangeIndex);
  range.setEnd(endNode, endRangeIndex);

  const surrounding = document.createElement("span");
  surrounding.className = "my-highlight-span";

  // This can't be used when cutting one text boundary.
  // Alternative is offered at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents
  // range.surroundContents(surrounding)

  const extracted = range.extractContents();
  surrounding.appendChild(extracted);
  range.insertNode(surrounding);
}

const text = "192.168.1.1";
transform(document.querySelector("#case-1"), text);
transform(document.querySelector("#case-2"), text);
transform(document.querySelector("#case-simple"), text);
```

```css
.my-highlight-span {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<p>Case 1:</p>
<div id="case-1">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is</em>
  <span class="ip-1">192</span>.<span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span>
</div>

<p>Case 2:</p>
<div id="case-2">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is
        <span class="ip-1">192</span>.</em><span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span>
</div>

<p>Simple case:</p>

<div id="case-simple">
  The computer address is 192.168.1.1
</div>

<hr />

<p>Desired Result:</p>

<div id="case-1-result">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is</em>
  <span class="my-highlight-span"><span class="ip-1">192</span>.<span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span></span>
</div>
<div id="case-2-result">
  <span class="foo-1">The computer address</span>
  <em>is
        <span class="my-highlight-span"><span class="ip-1">192</span>.</span></em><span class="my-highlight-span">
        <span class="ip-2">168</span>.<span class="ip-3">1</span>.<span class="ip-4">1</span></span>
</div>

<div id="case-simple-result">
  The computer address is <span class="my-highlight-span">192.168.1.1</span>
</div>
```